# What is the magnetic moments orientation of the free electrons in a current carrying wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

As described in this bellow illustration:

[image]

My problem with possible **Answer 1** in the above illustration is, considering also the *negligible drift linear velocity* of the free electrons inside the wire, a heads-to-tail N to S circular orientation of the electrons magnetic moments will generate no magnetic field in space like the case of a [toroid solenoid](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/toroid.html) also in this [WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential), where the field is ***B*=0** outside the toroid solenoid. You can also repeat this experiment with permanent magnets oriented in a circle with head to tail N-S poles connected and the result is the same. No magnetic field is generated around space.
See experiment below using a magnetic field viewing film and and an aluminum frame for placing the cube magnets in N head to S tail orientation:

[image: circular magnet]

There is no magnetic field inside and outside the ring.

**Answer 2** could be correct but then how the individual magnetic moments of the free electrons correlate to give the net uniform circular magnetic field around and along the wire?

Could be a silly question but I'm confused?

Comment: Why are the magnetic moments of the electrons important? The magnetic field is due to the current, not the magnetic moments.

Comment: IMO the magnetic field topology is always dictated by the magnetic dipole moments of free or unbound in the case of permanent magnets, electrons inside matter.

Comment: We all know about the aligned orientation of the magnetic moments of the unbound electrons in permanent magnets. However, no one seems to care about the orientation of the magnetic moments of the free moving electrons in a conductor wire? Is it that not a fundamental question? I don't think so...

Comment: In the classical microscopic view of current,

Comment: What is the origin of the figure?

Answer (score 2):

In the classical [microscopic view of current](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html) the electrons drift in the direction of the current.

[image: micrcurrent]

At this level, the magnetic field generated in the conductor by the current [is given by](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magin.html)

[image: condmagfield]

[From this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magmom.html) , the

> torque tends to line up the magnetic moment with the magnetic field B,

I would vote for answer 1.

You ask:

> Answer 2 could be correct but then how the individual magnetic moments of the free electrons correlate to give the net uniform circular magnetic field around and along the wire?

The current  $I$ comes from the drift velocity of the charge of the electrons, not form the dipole moment.

Comment: "The current I comes from the drift velocity of the charge of the electrons, not form the dipole moment." I never doubted that but I fail to see how a few cm/h are responsible for the magnetostatic field on the wire and not the coherent dipole moments of the free charges?

Comment: look at the numbers of the electron dipole, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment. Increasing the voltage increases the current, and B,it could not increase dipole moments as the number of electrons is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i think this is more correct, even if it is just a handwavy picture and a couple sentences, the electron flow in the wire is simply stochastic except for an average drift and essentially there are electrons moving with the current that look like this idealized, and the opposite situation as in the R and L in the picture moving against the current, but average is something like the picture i guess, i don't want to be precise because this isnt precise. its a mental picture of what is going on, in reality there are much richer configurations that average out to roughly the same kind of thing. macroscopic e&m doesnt mean much tbh, there are no charges without these dipole fields with moments that we ever really observe directly, so the origin of the macroscopic field configuration isnt either or you have to have a concrete model of the microscopic to determine that, if you want the standard answer go ask qed. the origin of the circular fields instead of spiral fields is just because both chiralities coexist in this kind of sketch of the situation. don't expect any real understanding from this picture or sentences, it is just a sketch, the magnetic field along the wire form the individual particles just cancel.

Comment: Very interesting physical interpretation of this cartoon assuming that the magnetic moments orientation is stochastic. However, IMHO this must be an initial state but after the random positioning becomes aligned and coherent in the current.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 2 is the least wrong. Due to Pauli paramagnetism there will be a tiny alignment of the conduction electron spins. However the response of a common copper wire is dominated by orbital [diamagnetic response](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/magprop.html) resulting from conduction electrons (Landau diamagnetism) and d-electrons.
[image: Pauli Paramagnetism: the conduction band splits in up and down spin bands slightly shifted in energy and more electrons end up in the up spin band.]

Pauli Paramagnetism: the conduction band splits in up and down spin bands that are slightly shifted in energy by Pauli interaction with a magnetic field. More electrons end up in the up spin band.

Answer (score 0):

In defense of the presented **Answer 2** as a possible explanation of the question asked herein I suggest the following:

There is no any theoretical basis or previous reference in the bibliography why the free electron's magnetic moments in the coherent electron current inside a wire conductor should be oriented (taking also into considerations their linear drift velocity) in a helical path trajectory along the wire (**Answer 1**).

On the other hand **Answer 2** is more plausible in my opinion and also backed up by theory regarding the movement of free electrons inside an Electrical field like that exiting at the center of a current carrying wire where E≠0. The free electrons will align axially to the linear electric field along the wire as shown in the below illustration and also known theory:

[image: movement of free electron]

(source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics) )

Where *p* is the momentum of the left chiral particle, and *S* is its spin. In left chiral particles like the electrons, the spin *S* is always opposite to the direction of momentum *p*. Also because the charge of the electron is negative -e, its magnetic moment (see red arrow) is also opposite to the spin S. Therefore a free electron will travel heads on with its magnetic moment aligned with its momentum *p* direction.

The *electromagnetic flux field* manifold inside a current carrying wire should look like this illustration below:

[image: electromagnetic flux manifold of current carrying wire]

Of course outside the wire macroscopically we see only the magnetic vector component of the total *electromagnetic flux* field along the wire.

Notice the spiraling *electromagnetic flux* total field shown above due to the very high charges density in the wire, is relativistically compressed into concentric circular magnetic flux outside the wire.

**Definitions:
Electromagnetic Flux --->** The Net magnetic and electric flux manifold of the total electromagnetic field inside and outside a current carrying wire.